# ¿Como puedo actualizar el ultimo insert ingresado con el mismo usuario?

Tags: php, sql

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$action = $_POST['action'];
$nombre_admin = $_POST['nombre_admin'];
if($action == 'entrada'){
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $entrada= date("d/m/y H:i:s");
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    MysqlQuery::Guardar("fichaje", "nombre_admin, entrada, ip", "'$nombre_admin', '$entrada', '$ip'")
```

A partir de aquí es cuando "falla"

```
}elseif($action == 'salida') {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $salida=date("d/m/y H:i:s");
    MysqlQuery::Actualizar("fichaje", "salida='$salida'", "nombre_admin='$nombre_admin'")
}}
```

La función de guardar

```
 public static function Guardar($tabla, $campos, $valores) {
    if (!$sql = Mysql::consulta("INSERT INTO $tabla ($campos) VALUES($valores)", Mysql::Conectar())) {
        die("Error al insertar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
    }

    return $sql;
}
```

la función de actualizar

```
public static function Actualizar($tabla, $campos, $condicion) {
    if (!$sql = Mysql::consulta("UPDATE $tabla SET $campos WHERE $condicion")) {
        die("Error al actualizar datos en la tabla $tabla");
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

Función consulta

```
public static function consulta($query) {
    if (!$consul = mysqli_query(Mysql::Conectar(), $query)) {
        echo 'Error en la consulta SQL ejecutada';
    }
    return $consul;
}
```

Me actualiza todos los dias de ese usuario, probe con estas dos opciones pero nada `and idfichaje=mysqli_insert_id(), and idfichaje=last_insert_id()`

Se podría hacer con un trigger o @@identity?

Comment: `MysqlQuery::Guardar()` podrias explicar esto de donde viene? ya que no puistes el codigo que se ejecuta detras de esto!

Comment: Listo ya lo añadi sorry

Comment: puedes explicar mejor lo que deseas es que aun sigo sin lograr entenderte que es lo que deseas hacer exactamente?

Comment: Okey, yo inserto una fila con un id, usuario y unas fechas para fichar, se inserta la fila correctamente, pero para actualizar los otros campos de un mismo usuario (ejemplo usuario raul) cuando voy a actualizar se actualiza todos los registros del campo de ese usuario porque el where esta por usuario pero no coge el id identificativo entonces actualiza todos los registro que ponga salida, faltaría filtrar por el ultimo id insertado de un usuario

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
public static function Guardar($tabla, $campos, $valores) {

    if (!$sql = Mysql::consulta("INSERT INTO $tabla ($campos) VALUES($valores)", Mysql::Conectar())) {
        die("Error al insertar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
    }
    // retornamos el ultimo insert   
    return mysqli_insert_id(Mysql::Conectar());
}
```

ahora para el update quedaria

```
// iniciamos 
@session_start(); // ordenar en lugar adecuado
if($action == 'entrada'){
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $entrada= date("d/m/y H:i:s");
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // almacenamos en un variable de session el ultimo id_insertado!
    if(empty($_SESSION['mysqli_insert_id'])){
            $_SESSION['mysqli_insert_id'] = MysqlQuery::Guardar("fichaje", "nombre_admin, entrada, ip", "'$nombre_admin', '$entrada', '$ip'");
    }else{
        die("no puedes volver a entrar, si no as salido!");
    }
    
}elseif($action == 'salida') {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $salida=date("d/m/y H:i:s");
    // validamos que entro
    if(!empty($_SESSION['mysqli_insert_id'])){
        $id_insert = $_SESSION['mysqli_insert_id'];
        MysqlQuery::Actualizar("fichaje", "salida='$salida'", "id='$id_insert'");
    }else{
        die("no puedes salir si no as entrado!");
    }
    
}}
```

Comment: Okey gracias pruebo y te digo